# neo4j match statment returns more nodes then wanted

Tags: neo4j, match

I have in my DB a user node that is connected to a userDevice node. On the relationship between them,  there is a property called pushId.

I'm trying to get a list of the pushIds and the user devices ids of a specific users.

```
match (user:User)-[r:WITH_DEVICE]->(device:UserDevice)
 where user.id="222" or user.id="243243"
RETURN  r.pushId,device.id
```

instead of 2 rows it duplicate one row twice and return 3 rows.

Comment: Are you sure that there is only one relationship between your user and your device? If you add `ID(r)` into your return statement you should be able to see if it is the same relationship.

Comment: You are right. I need to check how there is two relationships between the nodes. My mistake , thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use DISTINCT keyword

```
match (user:User)-[r:WITH_DEVICE]->(device:UserDevice)
 where user.id="222" or user.id="243243"
RETURN DISTINCT r.pushId,device.id
```

http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-return.html#return-unique-results

Comment: Doesn't work, I've tried..If both push ids of the user are the same, it returns me 1 row. I want it to return me exactly 2 rows